# Generalism - specialism index in microbial ecology

Tags: ecology, yeast, growth-media

I am doing research in Lipid metabolism in different yeast species and I would like to look into ecology of them.

I would like to classify them to a Generalist/specialist based on different Parameters (growth on carbon sources, pH, temperature,...).
I wonder if you have any experiences with that classification and if any of you know which indexes are used for that in microbial ecology?

Thank you very much for your answer!
Martin

Comment: Can you expand a little on your classification desires, you're not very specific.  There has been plenty of research on lipid metabolism, including [in yeast](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23340385).

Answer (score 2):

I've published a [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2011.00174.x/abstract) comparing different measures of specificity, if that is of any help. But if you plan to have, *e.g.*, measures of performance on carbon sources, pH, and temperature, then you'll have three measures of specificity (i.e. one for each).

Also, worth to have a look at Graham Bell's [inconsistency and responsiveness](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2409873?uid=3739464&uid=2&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21103219136401), as used by [Venail et al.](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v452/n7184/abs/nature06554.html) to classify specialists and generalists.